# What are some of the best sites to play chess?

Tags: online-chess, websites

What are some of the best sites for online chess?

Free sites with friendly communities are better.

Comment: Stack Exchange doesn't generally work well for questions that are just polling the community. The guidance is **"real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions."** That always sounds crazy to a new community, but trust me, avoiding these recommendation questions (especially early in the best) has proven itself time and time again as the core community starts to see where it all goes wrong. I urge you to read this short blog post: **[Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)** because I am running out of room here. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed .but why not converting this to community wikik instead of closing?

Comment: Because community wiki does not make this question any more of a "list your favorite chess site" poll. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Comment: I like Chessfriends.com. Free to use (with some limits), nice UI, and great Android/iOS apps!

Comment: I was using chesscube they were the best in matching skills, but they went commercial and website is in flash , I google and found chess24.com to be have very nice UI and that they have actual grandmasters playing over there. I will give it a try for a while and see how it goes

Comment: This is an old thread, but wanted to leave a link to [lichess.org](http://lichess.org) which is totally free, with no adverts and has extraordinary features for learning and analyzing games. It has great mobile apps, and works great in the browser too.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Chess.com](http://www.chess.com) has become a hot spot, with live and correspondence chess, along with tactical problems, articles, etc.  The live chess is OK, but not the best.

[ICC](http://www.chessclub.com) or [playchess](http://www.playchess.com) are the best for live chess, [FICS](http://www.freechess.org) if you want free, but it doesn't have as many titled players or features.  Those sites will also have video's, live commentary of top level tournaments, and much more.

Comment: I've used all these options, and I've found chess.com to have the friendliest community, and FICS by far the worst.

Comment: I've been a member of FICS, on and off, since 1996.  I've found both to be friendly with a few extreme exceptions.  As for community, FICS can't be beat with it's chat channels on everything from math, movies, etc...

Comment: I don't like the ads on chess.com - also, their free memberships are VERY limited.

Comment: @Sean: I have AdBlock.

Comment: Agree with the live chess part on chess.com, it needs to be improved even now.

Comment: Recently a new hotspot for live chess has arisen at lichess.org, and most chess streamers on Twitch (e.g. penguingim, KingsCrusher) usually use that site now.

Answer (score 11):

If you would like to play a lot of quick games, I would recommend FICS, or the Free Internet Chess Server.  Using a good interface like BabasChess or Winboard, it's response time is a lot crisper.  It has a long history with a lot of "culture", off-topic chat channels, 'bots', and a lot more master level players that some of the other sites.

Chess.com is also a good option.

Answer (score 10):

## ChessCube

[ChessCube](http://www.chesscube.com) has one of the nicest user interfaces, although it cannot be used with iPhone or iPads since it uses flash.

Comment: Agreed with you. ChessCube is pretty cool, Jerry from Chess-Network and KingsCrusher often frequent the Warzone tournaments. Also, ChessCube is now the number 1 chess tournaments site online - with over 400 tournaments per day. 

There are chat rooms, chess learning and mastering chess videos, and a great community.

Comment: ChessCube feels like playing in a very different world. Liked it, but doesn't give a classical feel.

Answer (score 9):

[Chess.com](http://www.chess.com/) is very popular and free. It also has a Facebook app that you can use to play. You can also play with a time limit of days/weeks and this is very useful if you rarely can find the time to sit down and have a serious game straight.

Comment: And it has both a iOS and Android app.

Comment: Answer is fine, except appears to be a duplicate.

Comment: Downvoted for duplicate.

Comment: @Sean Before downvoting for duplicate answer you should order the answers by the "oldest" and see how they have been posted chronologically. This site orders the answers by voting and that could be misleading. There was only James Tomasino answer when I typed mine. Also, it's very common that two or more people start typing similar answers concurrently and they post them basically at the same time

Comment: @Bryan See comment above.

Comment: @Sean This answer is 7 minutes *older* than Bort's answer.  +1

Answer (score 6):

[Red Hot Pawn](http://www.redhotpawn.com) has a great chess community and is available for free, or with a paid subscription.